# A faster memcmp: Breaking up array of bytes into large uints at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

### The problem / opportunity

Most people think of `memcpy` as hard / impossible to beat. I was surprised to find, that the same is not true of `memcmp`.  Simple comparisons of non-trivial types, result in unoptimised calls to `memcmp` from your standard C library:

https://godbolt.org/z/9f1Tr4nj4

[image]

The code below is a "faster memcmp" for specialised cases. Specifically for comparing two equal sized `std::array<std::byte, N>`

For N = 20  the hand rolled code inside `operator<=>` (using the below cast and byteswap helpers) is -- 2 x 64bit compares and 1 x 32bit one.

```cpp
    if (auto cmp = three_way<std::uint64_t>(&hash[0], &rhs.hash[0]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;

    if (auto cmp = three_way<std::uint64_t>(&hash[8], &rhs.hash[8]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;

    return three_way<std::uint32_t>(&hash[16], &rhs.hash[16]);
```

I am trying to make this code generic, such that it can generate the code for any 2 equal size `std::byte` arrays (within reason).

The entire reason for not just calling `memcmp`, is speed. The hand rolled code above is 2x faster than the `memcmp` on my machine, and the full application runs in 1:50min instead of over 3mins, as a result, so this matters. So it is important that whatever generic approach is used can produce (nearly?) equally good assembly. The hand rolled code, produce just a sequence of `mov` `cmp` `jne` (for short circuit evaluation) and `bswap` instructions, hence the speed.

https://godbolt.org/z/jrnKdadTe

[image]

How can I make it generic to any two equal size arrays of bytes? I feel like I am close with the recursive approach below, but my template programming is not good enough (yet).

This is the recursive function I am struggling with:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::strong_ordering array_three_way(const std::array<std::byte, N>& a,
                                               const std::array<std::byte, N>& b) noexcept {

  if constexpr(N == 0) {
    return std::strong_ordering::equal;
  } else {
    using next_type = largest_uint<N>;
    constexpr std::size_t next_size = sizeof(next_type);
    if (auto cmp = three_way<next_type>(&a[0], &b[0]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;
    // this recursive approach is not working out for me....when using std::array?
    return array_three_way(std::array<std::byte, N - next_size>(a[next_size]), std::array<std::byte, N - next_size>(b[next_size]));
  }
}
```

Maybe I just need to switch to "pointer and length" as a signature to the recursive `array_three_way`, and then perhaps provide an "entry wrapper" for convenience?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <bit>
#include <cassert>
#include <compare>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace hibp {

#ifdef __cpp_lib_byteswap
using std::byteswap;
#else
template <class T>
constexpr T byteswap(T n) noexcept {
  // clang-format off
  // NOLINTBEGIN
  #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define BYTE_SWAP_16 _byteswap_ushort
    #define BYTE_SWAP_32 _byteswap_ulong
    #define BYTE_SWAP_64 _byteswap_uint64
  #else
    #define BYTE_SWAP_16 __builtin_bswap16
    #define BYTE_SWAP_32 __builtin_bswap32
    #define BYTE_SWAP_64 __builtin_bswap64
  #endif
  // NOLINTEND
  // clang-format on

  if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint64_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_64(n);
  } else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint32_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_32(n);
  } else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint16_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_16(n);
  }
}
#endif

template <typename T, typename... U>
concept any_of = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);

// convert the sizeof(Target) bytes starting at `source` pointer to Target
// uses compiler intrinsics for endianess conversion if required and if `swap` == true
// caller responsibility to ensure that enough bytes are readable/dereferencable etc
// this compiles to a load and `bswap` which is very fast and can beat eg `memcmp`
template <typename T, bool swap_if_required = true>
constexpr T bytearray_cast(const std::byte* source) noexcept requires
    any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t> {

  static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::big ||
                    std::endian::native == std::endian::little,
                "mixed-endianess architectures are not supported");

  T value = *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(source); // NOLINT

  if constexpr (swap_if_required && std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
    return byteswap<T>(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}

template <typename T>
constexpr std::strong_ordering three_way(const std::byte* a, const std::byte* b) noexcept requires
    any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t> {
  return bytearray_cast<T>(a) <=> bytearray_cast<T>(b);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool
equal(const std::byte* a,
      const std::byte* b) requires any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t> {
  // don't bother swapping for endianess, since we don't need to for simple equality
  return bytearray_cast<T, false>(a) == bytearray_cast<T, false>(b);
}

template <std::size_t N>
using largest_uint =
    std::conditional_t<N >= 8, std::uint64_t,
                       std::conditional_t<N >= 4, std::uint32_t,
                                          std::conditional_t<N >= 2, std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t>>>;

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::strong_ordering array_three_way(const std::array<std::byte, N>& a,
                                               const std::array<std::byte, N>& b) noexcept {

  if constexpr(N == 0) {
    return std::strong_ordering::equal;
  } else {
    using next_type = largest_uint<N>;
    constexpr std::size_t next_size = sizeof(next_type);
    if (auto cmp = three_way<next_type>(&a[0], &b[0]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;
    // this recursive approach is not working out for me....when using std::array?
    return array_three_way(std::array<std::byte, N - next_size>(a[next_size]), std::array<std::byte, N - next_size>(b[next_size]));
  }
}

struct pawned_pw {

  std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {

    // this is what I would like to call
    return array_three_way(hash, rhs.hash);

    // this is the code I need to generate at compile time including any loop unrolling etc
    // for an std::array<std::byte, 20>
    if (auto cmp = three_way<std::uint64_t>(&hash[0], &rhs.hash[0]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;

    if (auto cmp = three_way<std::uint64_t>(&hash[8], &rhs.hash[8]);
        cmp != std::strong_ordering::equal)
      return cmp;

    return three_way<std::uint32_t>(&hash[16], &rhs.hash[16]);
  }

  bool operator==(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {
    if (bool cmp = equal<std::uint64_t>(&hash[0], &rhs.hash[0]); !cmp) return cmp;
    if (bool cmp = equal<std::uint64_t>(&hash[8], &rhs.hash[8]); !cmp) return cmp;
    return equal<std::uint32_t>(&hash[16], &rhs.hash[16]);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const pawned_pw& rhs) {
    for (auto&& b: rhs.hash) os << fmt::format("{:02X}", b);
    return os << fmt::format(":{:d}", rhs.count);
  }

  std::array<std::byte, 20> hash;
  std::int32_t              count; // important to be definitive about size
};
```

Comment: Have you considered just plugging in a better existing `memcmp` than the one that ships with your compiler, instead of inventing a new memcmp-optimization framework?

Comment: @BenVoigt I certainly would consider it. Any suggestions? --- although it has also been quite educational making this one...

Comment: *"The entire reason for not just calling memcmp, is speed. The hand rolled code above is 2x faster than the memcmp on my machine"*, just confirming: so you actually benchmarked an optimized build ('-O2' minimum), and/or verified from generated assembly, that your compiler/stdlib is not able to do the optimization you want?

Comment: @hyde I haven't done enough full benchmarking / assembler analysis to make any general statements, yet. However, while doing this project: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274768/212940 which does literally billions of these `std::array<std::byte, 20>::operator<` i found (by the random manual interrupt in the debugger technique while running a RelWithDebugInfo build (ie -O3)) - that the CPU was bottlenecked in `operator<` and spending > 90% of its time there. Replacing the naive `return hash < rhs.hash` (ie memcmp) with the hand rolled code above was > 2x speedup.

Comment: @hyde I realise it's a big call to make claims of being faster than `memcmp`, so I am planning to write a proper test-suite, to make sure the above TMP actually produces correct code in all cases (I already know it's correct for my 20GB of test data, but that's not a full test). Secondly i need to run more minimal, controlled microbenchmarks to make any more serious performance statements. It may be that the short-circuit evaluation after the first 8-bytes was helping my case? But then `memcmp` should have been benefitting from the same thing.

Comment: @hyde it is my understanding that `libstdc++` `std::memcmp` just calls `glibc` `memcmp` on my ubuntu 20.04 system. That is probably a pre-compiled shared object file (presumably -O2 or -O3). Perhaps `memcmp` would do somewhat better with `-flto`?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock What I think of when I think of memcmp optimizations is, the compiler does not call anything, it just generates the optimal (for known parameters) comparison code inline.

Comment: @hyde I saw `call memcmp` in the assembler on godbolt while I was still using `hash < rhs.hash`. That's what made me suspicious. Even just the `call` could be bad here, because there are only a few instruction to actually get the work done.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Interesting indeed, playing with Godbolt, `memcpy` gets nicely optimized, but `memcmp` just calls standard library... So this little project of yours has some merit indeed.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock: Here is one such existing implementation: https://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib  License might or might not work for you.  The author of that implementation mentioned a couple of others here: https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-help/2008-08/msg00000.html

Comment: Google search for "SSE2 memcmp" also generates good results such as https://gist.github.com/karthick18/1361842

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. Had a brief browse, and will look into further. Note that all these appear to be based on vector instructions, which I found to be significantly slower than plain 64/32bit uint load and compare. Just intuitively, that is because you are just shifting the "loop" into hardware microcode, whereas I am doing it at compile time. The signatures of their functions, take a length...

Comment: @OliverSchönrock: Vector instructions aren't doing a loop in microcode.  Modern processors really do have XOR gate arrays that are 256- and 512-bits wide.  And "count leading zeros" tells you the byte index where the difference was found, where the single-byte ordered comparison can take place.   Note that you found a 2x speedup over the library version, and Agner mentioned 5x speedup.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am not in a position to compare.  I do know that _mm_cmpestri() was much slower for me (and that does seem to run a loop in microcode). All I am saying  it's a different application. His (and Google's) looks like arbitrary runtime length algorithms. Mine is much more limited: statically known and equal length.

Comment: @BenVoigt the 4-5x is for memcpy... I can't find what he says for memcmp.. yet

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for that link to asmlib. I linked it in, it was easy to use. First run through.. inconclusive, possibly slightly slower than my static large integer approach, but needs a better micro-benchmark to really find out. The reason it's inconclusive, is because it's "fast enough" to push bottleneck elsewhere (most of the time). So asmlib could certainly be an option...

Comment: @BenVoigt I added some micro benchmark results to my answer below. Explains what I have been observing....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was closer than I thought? The "pointer & length" idea seemed to work out much more easily with basically the same structure. The assembler still looks good and it "appears to produce the correct answers at runtime".

here's the now working core recursion:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename Comp>
constexpr typename Comp::return_type array_compare(const std::byte* a, const std::byte* b,
                                                   Comp comp) noexcept {
  if constexpr (N == 0) {
    return Comp::equality_value;
  } else {
    using next_type                 = impl::largest_uint<N>;
    constexpr std::size_t next_size = sizeof(next_type);
    if (auto res = comp.template operator()<next_type>(a, b); res != Comp::equality_value)
      return res;
    return array_compare<N - next_size>(&a[next_size], &b[next_size], comp);
  }
}
```

And here fuller code, now pulled out into its own header, and its own namespace, and support "comparators", so we can use it for `three_way` (`operator<=>`) and `equal` (`operator==`)

*Note as @Useless pointed out below, there are alignment gremlins lurking here, which I still need to solve.*

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <bit>
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>

namespace arrcmp {

namespace impl {

#ifdef __cpp_lib_byteswap
using std::byteswap;
#else
template <class T>
constexpr T byteswap(T n) noexcept {

  // clang-format off
  #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define BYTE_SWAP_16 _byteswap_ushort // NOLINT
    #define BYTE_SWAP_32 _byteswap_ulong  // NOLINT
    #define BYTE_SWAP_64 _byteswap_uint64 // NOLINT
  #else
    #define BYTE_SWAP_16 __builtin_bswap16 // NOLINT
    #define BYTE_SWAP_32 __builtin_bswap32 // NOLINT
    #define BYTE_SWAP_64 __builtin_bswap64 // NOLINT
  #endif
  // clang-format on

  if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint64_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_64(n);
  } else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint32_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_32(n);
  } else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::uint16_t>) {
    return BYTE_SWAP_16(n);
  }
}
#endif

template <typename T, typename... U>
concept any_of = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);

// convert the sizeof(Target) bytes starting at `source` pointer to Target
// uses compiler intrinsics for endianess conversion if required and if `swap`
// == true caller responsibility to ensure that enough bytes are
// readable/dereferencable etc this compiles to a load and `bswap` which is very
// fast and can beat eg `memcmp`
template <typename T, bool swap_if_required = true>
constexpr T bytearray_cast(const std::byte* source) noexcept requires
    any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t> {

  static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::big ||
                    std::endian::native == std::endian::little,
                "mixed-endianess architectures are not supported");

  T value = *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(source); // NOLINT

  if constexpr (swap_if_required && sizeof(T) > 1 && std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
    return byteswap<T>(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}

template <std::size_t N>
using largest_uint =
    std::conditional_t<N >= 8, std::uint64_t,
                       std::conditional_t<N >= 4, std::uint32_t,
                                          std::conditional_t<N >= 2, std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t>>>;

} // namespace impl

struct three_way {
  template <typename T>
  constexpr std::strong_ordering operator()(const std::byte* a, const std::byte* b) noexcept
      requires impl::any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t> {
    return impl::bytearray_cast<T>(a) <=> impl::bytearray_cast<T>(b);
  }
  using return_type                           = std::strong_ordering;
  static constexpr return_type equality_value = std::strong_ordering::equal;
};

struct equal {
  template <typename T>
  constexpr bool operator()(const std::byte* a, const std::byte* b) noexcept requires
      impl::any_of<T, std::uint64_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint8_t> {
    // don't bother swapping for endianess, since we don't need to for simple
    // equality
    return impl::bytearray_cast<T, false>(a) == impl::bytearray_cast<T, false>(b);
  }
  using return_type                           = bool;
  static constexpr return_type equality_value = true;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Comp>
constexpr typename Comp::return_type array_compare(const std::byte* a, const std::byte* b,
                                                   Comp comp) noexcept {
  if constexpr (N == 0) {
    return Comp::equality_value;
  } else {
    using next_type                 = impl::largest_uint<N>;
    constexpr std::size_t next_size = sizeof(next_type);
    if (auto res = comp.template operator()<next_type>(a, b); res != Comp::equality_value)
      return res;
    return array_compare<N - next_size>(&a[next_size], &b[next_size], comp);
  }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Comp>
constexpr typename Comp::return_type array_compare(const std::array<std::byte, N> a,
                                                   const std::array<std::byte, N> b,
                                                   Comp                           comp) noexcept {
  return array_compare<N>(&a[0], &b[0], comp);
}

} // namespace arrcmp
```

And here a class using it:

```cpp
namespace hibp {

struct pawned_pw {

  std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {
    return arrcmp::array_compare(hash, rhs.hash, arrcmp::three_way{});
  }

  bool operator==(const pawned_pw& rhs) const {
    return arrcmp::array_compare(hash, rhs.hash, arrcmp::equal{});
  }

  std::array<std::byte, 20> hash;
  std::int32_t              count; // important to be definitive about size
};

} // namespace hibp
```

Some microbenchmarks of  arrcmp (mine above), glibc memcmp, and [asmlib](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#asmlib) (which was suggested in comments above)

[image]

And the moral of the story?

Each has their strengths... glibc is a very reasonable compromise, just not for my specific case (size 20, with most hashes discriminating much earlier), which is why I got that 2x speed up which the micro-benchmark validates. Also being slightly faster than asmlib at that size is validated here...

But the general case? glibc is pretty good? My arrcmp is very good at very small arrays up to size 30, perhaps.

Machine used:

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz

$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31
```

Code for the benchmark:

```cpp
#include "arrcmp.hpp"
#include "asmlib.h"
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <random>

static constexpr std::size_t size = 100;
static constexpr std::size_t step = 2;
static constexpr std::size_t seed = 2;

void arraycmp(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::mt19937_64                             rgen(seed); // NOLINT fixed seed
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dist(0, 255);

  auto idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(state.range(0));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash1{};
  hash1[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash2{};
  hash2[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  for (auto _: state) {
    auto result = arrcmp::array_compare<size>(&hash1[0], &hash2[0], arrcmp::three_way{});
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash1);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash2);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(arraycmp)->DenseRange(0, size - 1, step);

void asmlib(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::mt19937_64                             rgen(seed); // NOLINT fixed seed
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dist(0, 255);

  auto idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(state.range(0));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash1{};
  hash1[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash2{};
  hash2[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  for (auto _: state) {
    auto result = A_memcmp(&hash1[0], &hash2[0], size);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash1);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash2);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(asmlib)->DenseRange(0, size - 1, step);

void glibc(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::mt19937_64                             rgen(seed); // NOLINT fixed seed
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dist(0, 255);

  auto idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(state.range(0));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash1{};
  hash1[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  std::array<std::byte, size> hash2{};
  hash2[idx] = static_cast<std::byte>(dist(rgen));

  for (auto _: state) {
    auto result = memcmp(&hash1[0], &hash2[0], size);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash1);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(hash2);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(glibc)->DenseRange(0, size - 1, step);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pm100 I might do that later. Here it serves as an answer to the specific question first.

Comment: "Other suggestions for easier/better ways, please..."

Comment: @pm100 if you have any, you can post an alternative answer to the question above. The question was "broken code with unsolved problems". Not a code review. Now that I seem to have made progress, it might become one... but that's a whole separate step, and I may never do that. TBH, I find there are not many people over on CR.  Especially for c++.

Comment: I think you're vulnerable to alignment problems, especially if called directly with byte pointers. Some architectures will generate a bus error if you dereference an incorrectly-aligned pointer as uint64_t, and some will just silently run slower

Comment: @Useless Yes, you're right. I am aware. Haven't got around to researching that yet, and putting in what will probably be appropriate `static_assert(alignof(...)`  something... But good spot. Thank you.

Comment: @Useless I updated the code above and added a note about alignment.

Comment: The performance with glibc will heavily depend on your CPU (glibc selects at runtime one of 6 different implementations, with or without AVX, etc), and on the glibc version (the AVX2 version changed significantly between 2.33 and 2.34 for instance), so it would be good, next to any benchmark, to give a hint of what you are benchmarking.

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's fair, I was a little rushed. Info added. It's an old machine. No AVX2.